# Dreamweaver templates without.... Dreamweaver

Tags: templates, dreamweaver

I'm working on a website for someone.  Turns out they want support for Dreamweaver Templates.  I'm more of an Eclipse guy, and it seems like the only way to actually work with DWT is with Dreamweaver itself.  Dreamweaver is not something I'm willing to shell out $400 dollars for, especially since I'll only use it for.... templates.

Is there any way to manually create and use Dreamweaver templates?

Answer (score 3):

Dreamweaver templates are all based on specific tags in the form of html comments. If you research the different tags and their usage you can use Templates as well as Library items (.lbi's).

You could probably even create some auto completion rules in Eclipse.

I dont know if a list of all the tags and their uses exists directly but there is a perl module for generating them, although im not sure which version of DW its based on. But you might be bale to extract the various tags from it baring an easy to use authoritative document.

http://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::DWT

Actually now that i think of it... if they want you to take part in the build out youll need to find a library you can use in eclispse as an external tool or natively in order to simulate the various update features within Dremaweaver. That module might do the trick... if  its up to date that is.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the Dreamweaver CS4 template syntax by checking the following:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Dreamweaver/10.0_Using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7a79a.html

You can make them into snippets and be able to add them to any page you're working with.

Also, I've seen a ColdFusion component that is supposed to parse Dreamweaver templates and it seems instances, so perhaps checking through it's code may give you more info on how to find and use the template markup:
http://www.alagad.com/blog/post.cfm/dreamweaver-template-cfcs

Seem to me that since your client is demanding the use of Dreamweaver templates, that it would be easy enough to charge them for your purchase of Dreamweaver, and nothing comes out of your pocket.

Comment: Glad the docs for the tags does exist. ID like to second your thought of just billing the client for the purchase of DW though - its not that bad when used in code view and its no heavier than Eclipse resource/speed wise. Of course i havent had to fiddle with it since DWMX so things may have change din that respect :-)

Comment: Actually, this is more of a donation site, they just told me they needed templates half way though....

Comment: Well you could always use the Demo version if you can get it done in 30 days :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could go to their office and do the work there.

You could convince them to use something else, e.g. WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver Templates are documents where only part of the document can be edited. The tags which are preventing/enabling edtition are:

```
<!--TemplateBeginEditable name="*name anything that you would like to edit here ex. doctitle, head, js files, metatags or any part that you would like to remain editable. Anyway name here is irrelevant*" -->
```

and

```
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
```

to close editable area

And this is it. If you want to check it, you can use newest version of DW for free for a week from their website 
[Dreamweaver trial](https://creative.adobe.com/products/download/dreamweaver)

In newest version template files can be saved also as php or html files.

I hope this helps